# TypeScript 1.4: Using type unions

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I have a function `wrap` that can take either a `T` or a `Wrapped<T>` and returns a `Wrapped<T>`.

Declared in TS 1.0:

```
wrap<T>(value: Wrapped<T>, defaultValue?: T): Wrapped<T>;
wrap<T>(value: T, defaultValue?: T): Wrapped<T>;
```

Now in 1.4, I want to use union types to define the concept of "either a `T` or a `Wrapped<T>`"

```
class Bar {
   thing: Wrapped<number>;
   constructor(thing: number | Wrapped<number>) {
       this.thing = wrap(thing);
   }
}
```

But the type checker errors on the `this.thing` assingment with:

> Type Wrapped<number | Wrapped<number>> is not assignable to Wrapped<number>
>
> Type 'number | Wrapped<number>' is not assignable to type number

I understand that the error is that the value I'm passing to `wrap` is `number | Wrapped<number>` and `wrap` only knows how to handle `number` and `Wrapped<number>`;

So my first try was to go declare that it can handle `T | Wrapped<T>`;

```
wrap<T>(value: T | Wrapped<T>, defaultValue?: T): Wrapped<T>;
wrap<T>(value: Wrapped<T>, defaultValue?: T): Wrapped<T>;
wrap<T>(value: T, defaultValue?: T): Wrapped<T>;
```

But the type checker still errors. If I right click and go to definition I see that it's still binding to the third definition in the list rather than to my earlier, higher-precedence signature for `T | Wrapped<T>`.

Is this the expected behavior?

Am I supposed to resolve this manual with type guards? If so, could someone show me how to do it with this generic Wrapper that I have? How do I get a type parameter from my `thing` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles:

```
interface Wrapped<T> { value: T }
declare function wrap<T>(value: T|Wrapped<T>, defaultValue?: T): Wrapped<T>;

class Bar {
   thing: Wrapped<number>;
   constructor(thing: number | Wrapped<number>) {
       this.thing = wrap(thing); // No error
   }
}
```

General guidance for choosing between a union type and a function of two overloads is that if you *can* write it as a single-signature union type, you *should*.

Comment: So the answer is: remove the old signatures and allow the new signature to do the work of both. Cool. I was hoping for something simple like this. Thanks again Ryan! (You're fast on the draw).

Answer (score 1):

Simply combine the overloaded functions:

```
class Wrapped<T> {

    private _value: T;
    get value(): T { return this._value; }

    constructor(value: T) {
        this._value = value;
    }
}

class WrappHelper {

    public static wrap<T>(value: Wrapped<T> | T, defaultValue ?: T): Wrapped<T> {
        if (value instanceof Wrapped)
            return value;
        else
            return new Wrapped<T>(<T>value);
    }
}

var a = new Wrapped(100);
var b = 200;

var a1: Wrapped<number> = WrappHelper.wrap(a);
var a2: Wrapped<number> = WrappHelper.wrap(b);
```